# Why are Grey and Zach waiting in line in Jurassic world?

Tags: jurassic-world

In Jurassic World, when Zach and Grey get into their hotel room, their minder Zara, says that their aunt Claire got them VIP tickets so they do not have to wait in line.

> Your aunt has got you VIP access, so you can get on all the rides
>   without waiting in line...

But when they trying to get on the hamster ball ride, they seem to be waiting in line for a long time.

Answer (score 5):

### That *was* the VIP line.

> ***The two brothers were standing in the VIP line waiting to get in a
> gyrosphere.** The gyrospheres looked like giant hamster balls—plexiglass
> globes you could sit in, always staying upright while they spun
> through the countryside, passing close to the dinosaurs.*
>
> <sub><sup>Jurassic World - Junior Novelisation</sup></sub>

It would appear that a [one-hour wait was not unusual](http://uk.jurassicworldintl.com/park-cam/gyrosphere-line/), even for VIPs. There are only a small number of balls and lots of guests.

> *The visitors in line were not at all happy with this announcement. One
> said in Spanish, **“I waited in line with three kids for an hour!”**
> Another yelled in Chinese, “Do you know how much we paid for this
> trip?”*

Comment: Awesome, You know everything!!!

Comment: If there is a VIP line that is absolutely prioritized and that always has some people waiting, it doesn't seem to make any sense even trying to line up as a non-VIP. That's not a park I'd want to visit.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper - If you go to Disneyworld, they actually have six different classes of queuer; those who just turn up and wait, those who take "queue jump" tickets, those who have VIP passes, those who've paid for "*queue jump everything*" tickets, those that are disabled and those who do "*Rider Switch*" (where one person holds the baby and the other queues). Queuing times vary between three hours and less than five minutes. The key is keeping all these queues separated (typically they have three *actual* queues) so that ordinary queuers don't become unhappy about seeing people passing them.

Comment: @Valorum why not add that to the answer?